# Quick way to extend a set if we know elements are unique

Tags: python, set, union

I am performing multiple iterations of the type:

```
masterSet=masterSet.union(setA)
```

As the set grows the length of time taken to perform these operations is growing (as one would expect, I guess).

I expect that the time is taken up checking whether each element of setA is already in masterSet?

My question is that if i KNOW that masterSet does not already contain any of elements in setA can I do this quicker?

[UPDATE]

Given that this question is still attracting views I thought I would clear up a few of the things from the comments and answers below:

When iterating though there were many iterations where I **knew** `setA` would be distinct from `masterSet` because of how it was constructed (without having to process any checks) but a few iterations I needed the uniqueness check.

I wondered if there was a way to 'tell' the `masterSet.union()` procedure not to bother with the uniquness check this time around as I know this one is distinct from `masterSet` just add these elements quickly trusting the programmer's assertion they were definately distict. Perhpas through calling some different "`.unionWithDistinctSet()`" procedure or something.

I think the responses have suggested that this isnt possible (and that really set operations should be quick enough anyway) but to use `masterSet.update(setA)` instead of union as its slightly quicker still.

I have accepted the clearest reponse along those lines, resolved the issue I was having at the time and got on with my life but would still love to hear if my hypothesised `.unionWithDistinctSet()` could ever exist?

Comment: How do you know the elements are not in `masterSet`? Did you test the elements first?

Comment: No - on some iterations I know by the way setA is generated that no elements can be in masterSet

Comment: Just checking; there may have been an opportunity to update `masterSet` directly instead of having to do it later on.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You can use `set.update` to update your master set in place.  This saves allocating a new set all the time so it should be a little faster than `set.union`...

```
>>> s = set(range(3))
>>> s.update(range(4))
>>> s
set([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

---

Of course, if you're doing this in a loop:

```
masterSet = set()
for setA in iterable:
    masterSet = masterSet.union(setA)
```

You might get a performance boost by doing something like:

```
masterSet = set().union(*iterable)
```

---

Ultimately, membership testing of a set is O(1) (in the average case), so testing if the element is already contained in the set isn't really a big performance hit.

Comment: @jamylak -- Updating sets is much less common than `dict.update` or `set.union` for some reason.  (I had to `dir(set)` to figure out that it wasn't `set.extend` ;-)

Comment: I was going to suggest `|=`

Comment: @jamylak -- i would guess they end up being the same method ... Although maybe not.  with `|=`, the right hand side might need to be a set whereas that restriction is relaxed with `set.extend`.

Comment: oh right I remember coming to that conclusion as well and therefore didn't post that

Comment: Why is `set.union` slower than `set.update`? They seem to do the same thing

Comment: The source is helpful here -- https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2e279e85fece187b6058718ac7e82d1692461e26/Objects/setobject.c#L1115-L1136.  `c = a.union(b)` is effectively `c = a.copy(); c.update(b)` so it has that additional copy in the mix compared to `update`.

Answer (score 10):

As mgilson points out, you can use `update` to update a set in-place from another set. That actually works out slightly quicker:

```
def union():
    i = set(range(10000))
    j = set(range(5000, 15000))
    return i.union(j)

def update():
    i = set(range(10000))
    j = set(range(5000, 15000))
    i.update(j)
    return i

timeit.Timer(union).timeit(10000)   # 10.351907968521118
timeit.Timer(update).timeit(10000)  # 8.83384895324707
```

Answer (score 6):

If you know your elements are unique, a set is not necessarily the best structure.

A simple list is way faster to extend.

```
masterList = list(masterSet)
masterList.extend(setA)
```

Comment: On some iterations i need to test for uniqueness but on most I know that setA and masterSet are distinct. Is there no way to 'tell' the union() method (or use an alternative method) that I know the sets are distinct?

Comment: @mgilson you are assuming OP is not making any membership checks??

Comment: @jamylak -- Yes.  I feel that this answers the last sentence in the question.

Comment: on the other hand, a check in a set is o(1), so the overhead in union is not very large.

Answer (score 1):

For sure, forgoing this check could be a big saving when the `__eq__(..)` method is very expensive. In the CPython implementation, `__eq__(..)` is called with every element already in the set that hashes to the same number. (Reference: [source code for `set`](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/setobject.c?view=markup).)

However, there will never be this functionality in a million years, because it opens up another way to violate the integrity of a set. The trouble associated with that far outweighs the (typically negligible) performance gain. While if this is determined as a performance bottleneck, it's not hard to write a C++ extension, and use its STL `<set>`, which should be faster by one or more orders of magnitude.